# sqlite database manager for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I use this https://github.com/sanathp/DatabaseManager_For_Android sqlite manager for my android project which helps me a lot. It's a single class file that enabled me to see my database tables. So I didn't had to work blindly. I could see my database when I'm running the app on device with this manager. Is there any sqlite database manager library for iOS similar to this? I'm using swift for my project & for sqlite database I'm using Sqlite.swift project. Thanks.

Comment: I use parse.com. It's a simple interface and it's easy to use

Comment: how parse helps in that case?? could u plz explain...

Comment: use this simple library https://github.com/ryanfowler/SwiftData

Comment: Parse lets you see the database tables, you can modify them w/o the need of a query, it's an online database, simple interface, and it's mostly visual, so you don't work blindly

Comment: ok..I used a similiar service. It's called firebase. But for my current project I need sqlite..Thanks..@Bruno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though in android you have it as a activity i kind of have a separate mac app call SqliteBrowser by which i will manage the data

Check it here: http://sqlitebrowser.org/

I would locate the sqlite file in the documents directory(Or location where you store your sqlite file) and will load the sqlite file in this manager

- To check the data is inserted correctly
- To insert data and check whether i can retrieve via code
- The tables inserted into the DB are correct

Comment: `location where you store your sqlite file` that would be on an iOS device, if you read the question

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion @iPrabu

Answer (score 1):

also you can use sqdatabase sqlite database manager ı made this application for check database you can insert update browse and delete or only check your datas easy to use

link corrected sory you can check  [from here](http://www.sqdatabase.com)

Comment: link's dead.plz recheck